# Setting a view's background using a color saved in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuserdefaults

I have a main view controller, a "change background color" view controller, and a detail view controller.

When a user changes the background color via the change background color view controller, I do the following:

```
 NSData *colorData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:currentColor];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:colorData forKey:@"backgroundColor"];
 //currentColor is specified by user
```

This gets updated to the other view controllers through:

```
NSData *colorData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"backgroundColor"];
UIColor *color = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:colorData];
self.view.backgroundColor = color;
```

The problem I have is that the main view controller loads FIRST. Currently everything has a white screen when the app loads for the first time. My question is: how would I change it so that the application loads with a green color on every view controller to begin with, and after the user specifies the color, it stops displaying the green color and starts displaying the specified color?

I tried this with `viewDidLoad` but that doesn't work because it will just override the `NSUserDefaults` setting.

Comment: Did you remember to `synchronize` your `NSUserDefaults` after every change?

Comment: No I haven't done that. What is that?

Comment: Writes your changes to disk.

Comment: EXC_BREAKPOINT? Try restarting Xcode? Rebooting the device? Sacrificing a chicken? Something's screwey.

Comment: haha its because I used UIColor instead of NSData. NSUserDefaults doesn't accept UIColor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-[NSUserDefaults registerDefaults:]` is the thing you want here.  You call that with the values you want to be the "defaults" and then other callers will get those values. [Reference here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000318-CIHDDCDB)  You'll want this to run early in your app's lifecycle, probably in `– application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: Question, the default get over-written forever after the color is changed?

Comment: Yes. When you subsequently call `setObject:forKey:` (and call `synchronize`) that value will be written to disk and will be used over the default value from then on (until you change it by calling `setObject:forKey:` with a different value or `removeObjectForKey:`).

Comment: can you check the main post..I am having an issue

Answer (score 1):

As for your intention with setting your background to green every time until the user selects a color in your color selection view, would you like for this be done everytime the app is loaded into the foreground or everytime the app is launched? I suppose you could just set it up in your IB files (if you're using IB) or `viewDidLoad` should work.

If I'm understanding what you're trying to do correctly you could create another item in `NSUserDefaults` to track when the user has made a color selection, then you just check this flag when you're in `viewDidLoad` before setting the background to the selected color. However the reason I asked when you wanted to do this is to know when to reset that flag.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. Basically, I only want the greenColor to be shown if no other color has been selected. After another color has been selected, there is no use for the greenColor anymore. I think your idea about creating another item in NSUserDefaults to track it is probably a good idea. I'll try that

Comment: @EvilAegis Sounds like a standard default settings setup. In that case it might be better practice to go with @ipmcc's answer of using `registerDefaults`.